# Is there a way to update block to `latest` in case of a network forked by brownie?

Tags: python, brownie

I plan on something such as this:

1. Fork the network as `fork-network`
2. `chain.snapshot()`
3. Perform tests
4. `chain.revert()`
5. Update the network to latest state because my next tests will require data from newer blocks.

Is there a way to do step 5 in brownie without relaunching the local network?